# JavaScript convert JavaScript object to JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, http, object

What is the shortest method to convert a JavaScript object to a JSON object? The beneath is my JavaScript object.

```
{
  "body": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "action": "alert",
      "activityGroupNames": "test2"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "action": "alert",
        "activityGroupNames": "test3"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "action": "alert",
        "activityGroupNames": "test2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I making use of an inline code script in Microsoft automate that performs the following in JavaScript:

```
var threat = workflowContext.actions.Compose.outputs;
var value = Object.values(threat);
return value;
```

I am supposed to **HTTP POST** a JSON object in an API request, however, I am submitting a JavaScript object type and am unsure as to how I can change this. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if you require any further context.

Edit: The HTTP POST request is failing due to "*Object reference not set to an instance of an object*"

Comment: So `value` is what you're sending with your `POST` request?

Comment: @majusebetter i doubt it, `Object.values(...)` produces an `array`, not an `object`. Unless he sends `{ "body": values }`, i'm actually not sure what he's asking, it's pretty vague.

Comment: @majusebetter yes, that's correct. Apologies for my vagueness. the returned value variable is of type object and its content is shown in the snippet above.

Comment: @Teodor Sandu That's why I asked ;) Because there is no code showing what is actually being sent. The code looks like a function which is called by a "framework". And since the error occurs, my guess was that jupiterone1 tries to send the array directly.

Comment: Did you try something like `return { body: Object.values(threat) }`?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript provides with built-in method JSON.stringify() It will help you to convert JavaScript object into JSON and pass through HTTP Request

```
console.log(JSON.stringify({ x: 5, y: 6 }));
```

// expected output: "{"x":5,"y":6}"

Answer (score -1):

A common use of JSON is to exchange data to/from a web server.
When receiving data from a web server, the data is always a string.
Parse the data with JSON.parse(), and the data becomes a JavaScript object.

```
const json = '{ "fruit": "pineapple", "fingers": 10 }';
const obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj.fruit, obj.fingers);
```